# why "cin >>" works as a condition

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements

I know I can use `cin >>`as a condition. But I can't understand its functioning because it is unlike typical condition expressions like a `a < b`.
Why it can works as a condition ?

Comment: `std::iostream::operator>>` returns a value.  Values can be used in conditions.

Comment: To be more precise: Values that are convertible to boolean can be used in conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> a` return `cin`. When you put in in the `if`, the `operator bool` of `istream` is called, which return `cin.good()`. Look at [The documentation of ios::operator bool](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/).

This is the same as `if((bool)(cin >> a))` or `if((cin >> a).good())`.